# How to hide last table's column from a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide the last column of table because its have action links which is no need to export in excel file..so how to hide last table's column from a JavaScript variable?

```
var table = $('#UserWorkRecdsTbl').html();
table = table.hide('th:last-child, td:last-child');

tab_text = tab_text + table;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats your definition of "hide"?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `hide()` on the selector with the targeted elements in the following way:

```js
$("#UserWorkRecdsTbl th:last-child, #UserWorkRecdsTbl td:last-child").hide();
```

```css
td { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="UserWorkRecdsTbl" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did it ($("#UserWorkRecdsTbl th:last-child, #UserWorkRecdsTbl td:last-child").hide();) already which hiding totally from the page which I don't want.. I want to hide in excel..